# Plotly make_subplots vertical_spacing is causing huge white space below

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am new to Plotly and am trying to understand why it isn't working. I need horizontal Bar lines that displays the chart, here is the code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as opy


from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


def test():
    config = {'staticPlot': True}
    marker_color = 'rgba(81, 132, 4, 1)'

    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=3,
        cols=1,
        vertical_spacing=0,
        shared_xaxes=True,
    )

    fig.update_layout(
        margin = dict(t=10, b=10, r=0, l=0),
        plot_bgcolor = 'white',
        showlegend = False,
        autosize=True,
        xaxis=dict(
            showticklabels=False
        ),
    )

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        y=['Category 1'],
        x=[202],
        text=[202],
        orientation='h',
        marker_color=marker_color,
        textposition = 'outside'
    ))
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        y=['Category 2'],
        x=[310],
        text=[310],
        orientation='h',
        marker_color=marker_color,
        textposition='outside'
    ))
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        y=['Category 3'],
        x=[310],
        text=[310],
        orientation='h',
        marker_color=marker_color,
        textposition='outside'
    ))


    return opy.plot(fig, output_type='div', config=config)
```

And here is the output on the page:
[Graph has a huge white space below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK5tF.png)

I need to remove the white space below.

Comment: The matrix information is not set even though it is a subplot. Please set as follows. `fig.add_trace(go.Bar(...),row=1,col=1)`

Comment: yes, thank you this worked, I also needed to make the height smaller!